# Keep stopped EC2 standby server in sync with primary

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a primary EC2 server (Windows) and a backup that I keep stopped so I don't have to pay for it.  I'm looking for the easiest way to make sure that if I need to start the backup, it will have the latest files from the primary.  I could take a snapshot of the volumes but that takes a while and would lead to more downtime in the case of an unplanned outage.  Should I set up a synchronization to S3, and then sync from the same files after starting the backup?

My question is kind of hard to search for since if I search for information about syncing files I'll get stuff for keeping running EC2 instances in sync, and if I use the word "backup" I get info about backing up files to S3 and dropbox and such.

Comment: The solution... or whether you are actually solving the correct problem... depends on what kind of "files" you're talking about needing to keep in sync.  And, worth asking: you do know that stopping and starting an instance moves it to different hardware within the availability zone, and automatically reattaches the EBS volumes, ENIs, etc., right?  If snapshots are a theoretical solution, then your failure scenario isn't corrupt disks, and an instance stop/start would restore service.  So, exactly what failure mode are you trying to protect against?

Comment: As far as the type of files, the entire filesystem so a duplicate server can be started.  For failure modes, mainly 1) planned downtime (which is easier to deal with) and 2) total failure of the availability zone.  I know 2 is not likely but every now and then unlikely scenarios do occur.  Otherwise just the unknown - we can't reach the server for some undetermined reason and need to get a duplicate up as quickly as possible.

Comment: I suspect you'll find "the entire filesystem" to be non-trivial with Windows.  If loss of an AZ is a consideration, then making fresh snapshots is out, anyway -- if you lose the AZ or EBS within the AZ, you couldn't make snapshots if you wanted to.  But you could make volumes in another AZ from existing snapshots, since snapshots are stored redundantly in at least 3 AZs within the region.

Comment: Yes, I am finding it non-trivial.  This particular server is only changed when the web service it hosts is updated, so I don't need a fresh snapshot, just one that's been updated since the last release.

Comment: In that case, make a fresh AMI for each "release."  If you need to replace it, launch a new machine from the AMI.

Comment: That's a good idea, nice and simple.  And I can delete old AMIs to not get charged for them.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to this problem, and we don't have enough information to say which is best. I have a bunch of ideas, but I won't go into detail for any of them because each would take a bunch of time to write out. If you comment or edit your question to give more information I can refine things.

It sounds like you're going to manually hit "start" on the second instance if you notice the first instance down. Automation would probably be better.

A good way of ensuring you have one instance always running is auto scaling, with a maximum size of one. Usually this is used with elastic load balancing (ELB) so you don't have to worry about instance IP address, but you could probably write a startup script that grabbed an elastic IP on server startup, which would be cheaper than using an ELB. [This thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=498761) has some ideas on how to achieve that.

If you have a small subset of data files that change you could use Amazon [Elastic File System](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/). That way the EBS disk doesn't have to be kept up to date. If you have widely spread files that might not be practical.

It's easy to automate snapshots. There's probably a way with scripting to have an instance start up and associate itself with an EBS instance.

Rather than using one EBS instance, you could have one for operating system and one for data. It's probably possible for an instance to associate itself with a second EBS volume on startup. [This thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=99100) is one possible way I found with a quick Google search.

You could do what's more standard and keep both instances running behind a load balancer and sync them in real time, but that would increase your costs.

Comment: Thank you! We don't experience much down time so I'm looking for a cheap solution. I'll look into what you mentioned.

Comment: I've added [a link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=498761) with some ideas on how to use auto scaling with a single elastic IP. That's with EFS is possibly the cheapest way to improve availability simply.

Comment: I think I will see if I can use EFS.  From Amazon's description it sounds like even if their data center goes down the storage would be available because it's replicated across regions.  I can attach both instances to the same EFS store(s) and just start up the backup as needed.  And it doesn't cost that much more than EBS at the scale we're using.  I think multiple instances behind a load balancer is overkill for us.

Comment: You don't need to use EFS as a backup, you can use it as a disk that's attached to both instances. For example, with Wordpress, you could store the entire Wordpress folder on EFS, or just the wp-content folder.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was going to do, but: "Using Amazon EFS with Microsoft Windows Amazon EC2 instances is not supported."  I didn't mention it but this is a Windows server.

Comment: Also the problem with auto scaling is it sounds like it's fairly dumb about figuring out if there's an instance available.  If the instance is there but not responding, or it's up but the particular service I need is dead, it will think everything is fine and not spin up a new instance.  So that would require additional more complicated scripting to get that to work the way I would need.

Comment: EFS isn't supported for Windows, but that doesn't mean it doesn't work. You need an [EFS 4.1 client](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=234444).

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure I want to install a third party filesystem client on our production server and Windows doesn't come with a 4.1 client.  I think you meant NFS 4.1 and not EFS 4.1.  I saw mention of NFS on Linux with an SMB share to Windows but I don't think I want to go that route either.